# munmap_chunk: invalid pointer when changing location of data storage with std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm writing a program for a micro controller where I need to allocate the data of a vector to a specific location in memory (store it in Flash).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct struct_gauss {
    int mean;
    int sigma;
};

std::vector<struct_gauss> makeVector(size_t size, void* address, void* &endAddress) {
    std::vector<struct_gauss> dummy;
    struct_gauss **dummyPointer = (struct_gauss **) &dummy; // Address to metavalue of std::vector dummy (exists of 3 pointers)
    *dummyPointer = (struct_gauss *) address; // Point data of dummy to requested address
    *(dummyPointer+1) = ((*dummyPointer)+size);
    *(dummyPointer+2) = *(dummyPointer+1);
    endAddress = (void*) &(*dummy.end());
    return dummy;
}

int main()
{
    void* dummyPointer1 = malloc(1);
    void* dummyPointer2;
    auto vector1 = makeVector(10, (void*) dummyPointer1, dummyPointer2);
    auto vector2 = makeVector(10, (void*) dummyPointer2, dummyPointer2);
    vector1[9].mean = 10;
    vector2[0].mean = 5;
    std::cout<<"address of vector2 begin = "<< &(*vector2.begin())<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"vector1[9].mean = "<<vector1[9].mean<<"; vector2[0].mean = "<<vector2[0].mean<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This creates 2 vectors of 10 values in size that are back to back starting from pointer dummyPointer1. However when running this I get the following error:

```
address of vector2 begin = 0xf42c70    
vector1[9].mean = 10; vector2[0].mean = 5                                                                                                                                    
*** Error in `/home/a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000f42c70 ***                                                                           
Aborted
```

He errors when exiting the main() function because he can't deallocate vector2.

Why is that? How can I fix this?
Is there a better way?

P.S. I can keep the pointers of the vectors (the meta-values) in RAM but also write them to flash if that is better. Flash is used because I'm RAM limited and these vectors are written only when loading a new model from externally.

Comment: This is completely wrong from start to finish, as far as I can tell. Maybe allocators is what you're looking for.

Comment: You can't completely trample the memory of a vector object and expect it to still function afterward.

Comment: It appears that the code assumes the internal structure of `std::vector`. Interestingly, it works on MSVC, GCC, and clang for the 1 vector case, but it appears to be undefined behavior all around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things that look horrible, and I apologize for the bluntness, but I really do mean '*horrible*' in this context.

> ```
> std::vector<struct_gauss> makeVector(size_t size, void* address, void* &endAddress) {
>     std::vector<struct_gauss> dummy;
>     struct_gauss **dummyPointer = (struct_gauss **) &dummy; // Address to metavalue of std::vector dummy (exists of 3 pointers)
>     *dummyPointer = (struct_gauss *) address; // Point data of dummy to requested address
>     *(dummyPointer+1) = ((*dummyPointer)+size);
>     *(dummyPointer+2) = *(dummyPointer+1);
>     endAddress = (void*) &(*dummy.end());
>     return dummy;
> }
> ```

Nothing about this code looks safe or advisable. There seems to be a number of assumptions being made about how the `std::vector` object is constructed in memory, and even if your assumptions are correct, you've still failed to properly construct the `std::vector` object in a standard-compliant manner.

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     void* dummyPointer1 = malloc(1);
>     void* dummyPointer2;
>     auto vector1 = makeVector(10, (void*) dummyPointer1, dummyPointer2);
>     auto vector2 = makeVector(10, (void*) dummyPointer2, dummyPointer2);
> ```

This is just flat-out wrong. You're allocating a single byte to store the vector inside, expecting the object to store 10 bytes, and nowhere have you actually allocated the space for the underlying array.

In short, I think you've hit a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), full stop. The problem you're trying to solve is "how do I make `std::vector` allocate memory from flash memory"

The way you normally solve these kinds of problems is with custom allocators.

```
template<typename T>
struct allocator {
    typedef size_t size_type; 
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T * pointer;
    typedef T const& const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T const& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;
    pointer allocate(size_t size) {
        void * mem = micro_controller_api::allocate_flash_memory(size); //I don't know what your API looks like

        //You'll need something else if you're not able to throw exceptions in your code.
        if(!mem) throw std::bad_alloc(); 

        //On its own, this would be unsafe, but std::vector uses placement new with its memory,
        //so you don't need to worry that the cast here would risk some undefined behavior.
        return static_cast<pointer>(mem);
    }
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_t) noexcept { micro_controller_api::free_flash_memory(static_cast<void*>(p)); }

    allocator() = default;
    template<typename U>
    allocator(allocator<U> const&) {}

    pointer address(reference r) const {return addressof(r);}
    const_pointer address(const_reference r) const {return addressof(r);}

    bool operator==(allocator const&) const {return true;} //All allocators are the same
    bool operator!=(allocator const&) const {return false;}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<struct_gauss, allocator<struct_gauss>> vector1(10);
    std::vector<struct_gauss, allocator<struct_gauss>> vector2(10);
    //Do whatever; vector1 and vector2 are, as far as anyone is concerned, perfectly valid vectors
}
```

Mind you, I've not written allocators myself before, and the one I'm providing here is based on a template shown on a [C++ reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator), (*Edit: I've also added some stuff by referencing [this page](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/15-3.html)*) so it's possible I've made mistakes. But hopefully all of this is enough to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your clear response. I know that I'm hacking std::vector in a horrible way.
However, I don't know how to allocate a specific memory address. To my knowledge there is no API for flash allocation (None of the µC examples from the vendor (I'm using a EFM32 Wonder Gecko from Silicon Labs) preallocate the memory, they hope that they don't cross into program memory. And I also don't know how to allocate in standard C++ some memory at a very specific address.